# Spark (Scala): retain column order when writing DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Dataframe, to be write in south-path, has the following structure: "field1, field2, field". I see it by apply .show()-method.

But when I write it in hdfs-path:

```
 dataFrame
      .repartition(1)
      .write
      .parquet(outputPath)
```

output file has the structure with changed order of fields:

```
{"field2": "", "field1": "", "field3": ""}
```

I suppose it's related with peculiarity of parallel execution.
Is there any way to retain the original order of columns when writing of DataFrame?

Comment: This has nothing to do with parallelism https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19005

Comment: ok, but how to save the order when writing DataFrame ?

Comment: You are most likely using an old spark version.

Comment: Spark version: 2.3.0

Comment: Works fine on 2.4.5 (oldest version supported by Azure Databricks). The fact that you're using a version released 4 years ago (February 28, 2018) is quite troubling.